# in asp.net core mvc - post id variable from one datatable to filter a stored procedure as source for 2nd datatable

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, datatables

In asp.net core mvc with entity framework. I have a working datatable with a js button which selects the row id. I would like to post this id as a parameter  to a server side stored procedure in a controller which loads and filters a 2nd data table. So far I have tried ajax and query string but the variable always arrives at the controller as null . Not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is my initial view, controller and 2nd data table view.

````
@{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
        Layout = "_Layout";
    }
    
    
    
    
    <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    <div class="container">
    
    
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>             
                        <th>Last Name</th>                 
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    @section Scripts {
        <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#myTable').DataTable(
                    {
                        ajax: {
                            url: "StammAll/GetStamm",
                            type: "POST",
                        },
                        processing: true,
                        serverSide: true,
                        filter: true,
                        columns: [
                            { data: "id", name: "id" },
                            { data: "name", name: "Name" },
                           
                            {
                                "data": "id", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                                    return '<button type="button" id="' + data + '" class="btn btn-primary btnEdit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>'
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                );
    
    
                // ---------------    id variable to button
    
                $(document).on("click", ".btnEdit", function () {
                    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    
    
    
                    // Send the id to the server
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/OP/GetOP",
                         data: { id: id },
                       // data: '{id: ' + JSON.stringify(id) + '}',
                        success: function (result) {
    
                            window.location.href = '/OPGet/OP?id=' + encodeURIComponent(id);
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            // Handle error if needed
                        }
    
                    });
    
    
    
                });
    
                             
            });
    
    
    
    
        </script>
    
    }```


 

       ```  controller
    namespace HCH_Research_App.Controllers
    {
        public class OPController : Controller
        {
            private OPDbContext _context;
            public OPController(OPDbContext context)
            {
                _context = context;
            }
        
    
            public IActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }
    
            [HttpPost]
            public JsonResult GetOP()
            {
    
                string par = "11";
    
                // Call the stored procedure with the parameter
    
                var empList = _context.QsOpShorts
                   .FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE sp_OP_short @id", new SqlParameter("@id", par))
                    .ToList();
       
                var returnObj = new { data = empList };
          
    
                return Json(returnObj);
           
            }
    
    
    
    
        }
    }
    ```

  

      ``` view 2 
    
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
        Layout = "_Layout";
    }
    
    <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    <div class="container">
    
    
    
    
    
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>OP Date</th>
                    
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    @section Scripts {
        <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#myTable').DataTable(
                    {
                        ajax: {
                            url: "OP/GetOP",
                            // url: "StammAll/GetStamm",
                            type: "POST",
                        },
                        processing: true,
                        serverSide: true,
                        filter: true,
                        searching: false,
                        info: false,
                        lengthChange: false,
                        columns: [
                            { data: "id", name: "id" },                     
                            { data: "op_Datum", name: "Op_Datum" },
                        
    
                        ]
                    }
                );
    
    
    
    
            });
    
    
    
    
    
        </script>
    
    
    }
    
    ```
````

Comment: " So far I have tried ajax and query string but the variable always arrives at the controller as null " Where do you set the breakpoint to see the id ? What's `window.location.href = '/OPGet/OP?id=' ` ? What action do you want to pass the id ? Besides how do you define the two views ?

Answer (score 0):

> but the variable always arrives at the controller as null

Do you try to add parameter `id` in the GetOP() ?

```
 [HttpPost]
  public JsonResult GetOP(string id)
  {
    ...//do your staff
  }
```

And set a breakpoint at GetOP(string id),
result:
[image]